# Cannot Open Internal Bluetooth in Ubuntu on a Mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac, bluetooth

I'm trying to run a script that involves opening up and using internal bluetooth. The script defaulted to opening up an external Bluetooth located at `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but since it's internal nothing exists at that location. If I run `lsusb |grep Bluetooth`, I get

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05ac:8286 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
```

I have tried running the script using `/dev/bus/usb/002/004` or `/dev/bus/usb/002/008` in place of the old location, but I only get an error saying `buffer overflow detected` followed by a memory map. Should I find a way to mount this bluetooth device or is there another way to open it that I don't know about?